# Setting parent embeds widget in main window menu bar

Tags: pyqt

What is the proper way to set a widget's parent so that properties, like window icons, can be accessed from children?

I have created a widget to display application documentation in a QWebEngineView.  I would like the widget to use the same window icon as the parent.  When the parent is `None`, the widget works as expected (excluding, of course, that there is no window icon):

[image]

However, when I set the parent, the documentation widget embeds itself in the main window's menu bar:

```py
# SETTING PARENT HERE CAUSES GRIEF
self.doc_viewer = DocumentationViewer(self)
```

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on.  Furthermore, I find that if I use a QDialog instead of a QWidget, everything works fine.  I'm unable to explain why.

Full code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets


class DocumentationViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, index="docs/index.html"):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        if parent:
            self.setWindowIcon(parent.windowIcon())

        self.setWindowTitle("Manual")

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

        self.index = QtCore.QUrl('file:///' + index)
        self.view.load(self.index)

    def init_widgets(self):
        # history back
        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowBack)
        self.history_back_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.history_back_button.setIcon(icon)

        # history forward
        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowForward)
        self.history_forward_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.history_forward_button.setIcon(icon)

        # reload
        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_ArrowUp)
        self.reload_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.reload_button.setIcon(icon)

        # find forward
        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaSeekForward)
        self.find_forward_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.find_forward_button.setIcon(icon)

        # find backward
        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaSeekBackward)
        self.find_backward_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
        self.find_backward_button.setIcon(icon)

        # find box
        self.find = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.find.setPlaceholderText('Find...')

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

    def init_layout(self):
        navigation_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.reload_button)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.history_back_button)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.history_forward_button)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget(), stretch=1)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.find)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.find_backward_button)
        navigation_layout.addWidget(self.find_forward_button)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5 ,5)
        layout.addLayout(navigation_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        icon = QtWidgets.QApplication.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_TitleBarMenuButton)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.menu = self.menuBar()

        # File menu
        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.menu_file = self.menu.addMenu('&File')
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.exit_action)

        # Help menu
        self.manual_action = QtWidgets.QAction("&Manual", self)
        self.manual_action.triggered.connect(self.on_manual_action)

        self.menu_help = self.menu.addMenu('&Help')
        self.menu_help.addAction(self.manual_action)

        # SETTING PARENT HERE CAUSES GRIEF
        self.doc_viewer = DocumentationViewer()

    def init_layout(self):

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Main Widget Content"))

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def on_manual_action(self):
        self.doc_viewer.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change to `DocumentationViewer(QtWidgets.QDialog)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three alternatives.

1. [as suggested by eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405201/setting-parent-embeds-widget-in-main-window-menu-bar#comment119141972_67405201), inherit from QDialog instead of QWidget;
2. use the `Window` flag for the `flags` keyword in the widget constructor (which is what QDialog actually does on its own), which keeps Qt parenthood while ensuring that the widget has its own window:

   `super().__init__(parent=parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window)`
3. set a default window icon for the whole QApplication with [`setWindowIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#windowIcon-prop).

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that the icon could be set application-wide.